# How do I combine expand function output with other properties in SQL Projection for OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I have two classes: Identity and User with edges from User to Identity. I need to construct a SQL query that will get the User RID as well as some properties from Identity field.
For example my Identity class has emailAddress, firstName, and lastName property. My User can have multiple outgoing edges to identity records. 
However, this statement doesn't work as expected:

`SELECT expand(in()), emailAddress, firstName, lastName from Identity where email="abcd@temp.com"`

The result of above is just the output of expand(in())
Am I stuck with making two separate calls/queries, one to get props from Identity, and the other to use expand function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could jump on the edge and then you have in/out with Identity and User reference and then make the projection like this

```
select  out.emailAddress, out.firstName, out.lastName from (SELECT expand(inE()) from Identity where email="abcd@temp.com")
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want to do. I want to join the Identity fields with the User fields. IOW, I want select out.firstName, out.lastName, email, password from (select expand(inE()) from Identity where email="abcd@temp.com")

Comment: To reference Identity you have to use in

select out.firstName, out.lastName, in.email, in.password from (select expand(inE()) from Identity where email="abcd@temp.com")

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, this select statement lets you select properties from both User and Identity.

- FROM clause, points to the edge (sitting between User and Identity)
- SELECT outV('User').property, points to start-node User, going out to edge
- SELECT inV('Identity').property, points ending node Identity, coming in from edge

In the SELECT clause you can fetch any property by prefixing it with **outV('User').** property and/or **inV('Identity')**.property.

In the WHERE clause you can search on any property by prefixing it with **outV('User').** property and/or **inV('Identity')**.property.

```
SELECT 
outV('User').firstName as name,
inV('Identity').email as email, 
somePropertyFromEdgeName as prop
FROM EdgeName //name of the edge between User and Identity
WHERE outV('User').firstName = 'John'
or inV(Identity').email = '...' 
// etc....
ORDER BY email asc, prop desc
```

Comment: please consider adding at please a sentence explaining why and how your code snippet does reply to the OP question.